# ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged doesn't return the selected value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, events, combobox

Developing an application using vb.net in visual studio 2019 I got the next error
I have 1 combobox on my form, when I change the index I need take the selected value an assign it to the variable courrentQRQC.

This is my code

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cBox_folio.SelectedIndexChanged
 
        courrentQRQC = cBox_folio.Text

end sub
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihKcW.png)

cBox_folio.Text return the value " " when I select an item

Comment: I suspect that the `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDown` when it should be `DropDownList`.

Comment: You're supposed to check whether `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0`. To get the SelectedItem's content as a string, `dim selectedText = ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)`. Don't get the `Text` from a ComboBox.

Comment: @Roberto Madrid, based on my test, I can get the correct result by using the same code with you. Maybe other code affect the result. I recommend that you use **ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()** code to replace **combobox1.Text**.

Comment: @Jack J Jun - MSFT  ...so you may get `System.Data.DataRowView`, `MyFancyClassObject` etc. as result. [ListControl.GetItemText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext) returns the values determined by the `DisplayMember` property or `value.ToString()` in case of simple binding or direct assignment to Items collection.

Comment: Assuming you have set the Display member and Value member. .SelectedValue should do it.

Comment: Tnx for their comments, i got other code affect the result previously